# guardar la opción de una lista dinámica en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola tengo un cuestionario con opciones de selección de una lista que viene de una base de datos

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="sel1">Quien Realizara la Auditoria?:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select>
               <option value="0" name="auditor" id="auditor">Selección:</option>
               <?php
               $query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY id");             
               while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo '<option value="'.$valores[id].'" name="auditor" id="auditor" >'.$valores[Nombre].'</option>';
               }
               ?>
           </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

y quiero guardar los valores seleccionados. pero me manda este error

Notice: Undefined index: auditor

este es mi archivo donde lo voy a guardar

```
<?php
$Fdeseada = $_POST["deseada"];
$Flimite = $_POST["limite"];
$auditor = $_POST["auditor"];
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema es que los atributos `name` y `id` deben ir en el `select` no en el `option`

Tu código deberia funcionar así :

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <label for="sel1">Quien Realizara la Auditoria?:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name="auditor" id="auditor">
               <option value="0">Selección:</option>
               <?php
               $query = $conexion -> query ("SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY id");             
               while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo '<option value="'.$valores[id].'" >'.$valores[Nombre].'</option>';
               }
               ?>
           </select>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

Ahora el error no debería aparecer, ¿Te ha funcionado?

Comment: De paso, en la pregunta nos debería confirmar si el select está dentro del formulario :D